Maven Publish Error in Gitlab CI - Task Dependency Issue
I'm trying to publish with maven-publish my library with Gitlab CI but I'm getting:
Reason: Task ':core:common:publishMyPublishPublicationToMavenLocalRepository' uses this output of task ':core:common:bundleProdReleaseAar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':core:common:bundleProdReleaseAar' as an input of ':core:common:publishMyPublishPublicationToMavenLocalRepository'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':core:common:bundleProdReleaseAar' from ':core:common:publishMyPublishPublicationToMavenLocalRepository' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':core:common:bundleProdReleaseAar' from ':core:common:publishMyPublishPublicationToMavenLocalRepository' using Task#mustRunAfter.

But when I'm running it locally everything works perfectly.
I was trying with these solutions https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/26091#issuecomment-1962863517 but it's not working, or maybe I'm using it incorrectly?
This is my code responsible for uploading all modules as aar files into Gitlab package Registry:
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

afterEvaluate {
    if (!plugins.hasPlugin("android")) {
        publishing {
            publications {
                myPublish(MavenPublication) {
                    version releaseVersion
                    if (plugins.hasPlugin("java")) {
                        from components.java
                    } else if (plugins.hasPlugin("android-library")) {
                        artifactId = "${project.name}"
                        artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-prod-release.aar")
                        pom.withXml {
                            def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                            def dependenciesManagementNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencyManagement').appendNode('dependencies')
                            configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                                if (it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified" == it.name)) {
                                    if (it.name.endsWith("-bom")) {
                                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesManagementNode.appendNode('dependency')
                                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                                        dependencyNode.appendNode('scope', "import")
                                        dependencyNode.appendNode('type', "pom")
                                    } else {
                                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                                        if (it.group.contains("mflota-android")) {
                                            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', releaseVersion)
                                        } else {
                                            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            repositories {
                mavenLocal()
                maven {
                    url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/...."
                    credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                        name = "Private-Token"
                        value = TOKEN
                    }
                    authentication {
                        header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Maybe there is also a simpler way to do that?
